# How to select parent and all subnodes in JXTreeTable?

Tags: java, swing, selection, swingx, jxtreetable

I need to select rows in JXTreeTable for clicked parent and all of its subnodes. In older Swingx with deprecated JXTreeTable it could be done with TreeSelectionListener. I had listener (mTable is deprecated JXTreeTable):

```
 mTable.addTreeSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener() {    
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt) {
                selectionPerformered(evt);
            }
        });
```

and method selectionPerformed(evt):

```
private void selectionPerformered(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt) {
        boolean unlock = true;
        TreePath parentPath = evt.getNewLeadSelectionPath();
        if (parentPath != null) {
            ListSelectionModel list = mTable.getSelectionModel();
            TreeNode node = ((TreeNode) (parentPath.getLastPathComponent()));
            if (node.getChildCount() > 0) {
                TreePath path = new TreePath(
                        ((DefaultTreeTableModel) mTable.getTreeTableModel()).getPathToRoot((TreeTableNode) node.getChildAt(0)));
                int begin = mTable.getRowForPath(path);
                path = new TreePath(
                        ((DefaultTreeTableModel) mTable.getTreeTableModel()).getPathToRoot((TreeTableNode) node.getChildAt(node.getChildCount() - 1)));
                int end = mTable.getRowForPath(path);
                list.addSelectionInterval(begin, end);
            }
            unlock = false;
        }
        disableUnlock(unlock);
    }
```

When I clicked "Components" event was fired few times and with list.addSelectionInterval(begin, end); selection worked fine and looked like this:

[image: good one]

But now, with new swingx 1.6, with new JXTreeTable, when I click "Components" in debug mode, this event is fire only once, so the result looks like this :

[image: bad one]

For example if I click "admin" program selecting this row and next 3 rows with its children. but if I click "Components" I need to select this row and all rows for children and every child's children. If u know what I mean :) Is it any way to fire this event? Or maybe there's another way to do selection?

Comment: this issue was/were solved / answered on this forum a few times, have to combine JTable & JTree selection (its clone from SwingX) better answerrs on SwingX forums, inc. selection & hightlighter

Comment: Also consider [`Outline`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).

Comment: might be a bug - please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: this is just a small part of bigger project, I don't know how to show you working demo.